# Google Chrome extension - how to remove entry from top sites list (Omnibox suggestions)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, autocomplete, address-bar

I can easly remove an entry from Chrome's history:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html#method-deleteUrl

but a deleted webpage is still showing up in the suggested sites in the address bar (called Omnibox). I found, these entries are in `.config/google-chrome/Default/Top\ Sites`. How can I delete a single entry from this list (through Google Chrome API)?

Answer (score 7):

You can remove entries from the list using the following steps:

1. Start typing the name of the website or whatever
2. Press <kbd>↓</kbd> on your keyboard, a list of all of the "remembered" entries should appear.
3. Using <kbd>↑</kbd> & <kbd>↓</kbd> highlight an entry you would like to delete.
4. Press <kbd>delete</kbd>. (Note that you may need to use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> (Ubuntu) in some instances, like if the remembered entry is in the address / URL bar).
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until satisfied.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for an annoying search suggestion (indicated by a magnifying glass icon)

Answer (score 1):

You can *get* them in a leading version of Chrome with the topSites API: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/topSites.html

I'd dig through this stuff: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/api_index.html

Looks like the chrome.types api might have some helpful stuff, but I don't have much expertise on this particular thing I can offer you :(

Comment: So I can't just remove Top site... but I'm still looking for way do remove suggested site directly in omnibox when sites are suggested. Can I access it from BOM, or sth?

Comment: on of the new settings api's might offer that... not sure

Comment: you can also override the new tab page, use the above api to get the top sites, but offer a setting to remove them

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to remove it,
if u are using windows machine, uninstall "Search Product" application from installed programs